# How to get data out of Wrapped Array in Apache Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataframe with rows that look like this:

```
[WrappedArray(1, 5DC7F285-052B-4739-8DC3-62827014A4CD, 1, 1425450997, 714909, 1425450997, 714909, {}, 2013, GAVIN, ST LAWRENCE, M, 9)]
[WrappedArray(2, 17C0D0ED-0B12-477B-8A23-1ED2C49AB8AF, 2, 1425450997, 714909, 1425450997, 714909, {}, 2013, LEVI, ST LAWRENCE, M, 9)]
[WrappedArray(3, 53E20DA8-8384-4EC1-A9C4-071EC2ADA701, 3, 1425450997, 714909, 1425450997, 714909, {}, 2013, LOGAN, NEW YORK, M, 44)]
...
```

Everything before the year (2013 in this example) is nonsense that should be dropped. I would like to map the data to a `Name` class that I have created and put it into a new dataframe.

How do I get to the data and do that mapping?

Here is my `Name` class:

```
case class Name(year: Int, first_name: String, county: String, sex: String, count: Int)
```

Basically, I would like to fill my dataframe with rows and columns according to the schema of the `Name` class. I know how to do this part, but I just don't know how to get to the data in the dataframe.

Comment: Is it a column which contains a WrappedArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data is an array of strings like this:

```
val df = Seq(Seq("1", "5DC7F285-052B-4739-8DC3-62827014A4CD", "1", "1425450997", "714909", "1425450997", "714909", "{}", "2013", "GAVIN", "STLAWRENCE", "M", "9"),
    Seq("2", "17C0D0ED-0B12-477B-8A23-1ED2C49AB8AF", "2", "1425450997", "714909", "1425450997", "714909", "{}", "2013", "LEVI", "ST LAWRENCE", "M", "9"),
    Seq("3", "53E20DA8-8384-4EC1-A9C4-071EC2ADA701", "3", "1425450997", "714909", "1425450997", "714909", "{}", "2013", "LOGAN", "NEW YORK", "M", "44"))
  .toDF("array")
```

You could either use an `UDF` that returns a case class or you can use `withColumn` multiple times. The latter should be more efficient and can be done like this:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("year", $"array"(8).cast(IntegerType))
  .withColumn("first_name", $"array"(9))
  .withColumn("county", $"array"(10))
  .withColumn("sex", $"array"(11))
  .withColumn("count", $"array"(12).cast(IntegerType))
  .drop($"array")
  .as[Name]
```

This will give you a `DataSet[Name]`:

```
+----+----------+-----------+---+-----+
|year|first_name|county     |sex|count|
+----+----------+-----------+---+-----+
|2013|GAVIN     |STLAWRENCE |M  |9    |
|2013|LEVI      |ST LAWRENCE|M  |9    |
|2013|LOGAN     |NEW YORK   |M  |44   |
+----+----------+-----------+---+-----+
```

Hope it helped!