# How to remove/filter element from WrappedArray column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm facing an issue with manipulating a `WrappedArray` column. I want to remove/filter element from the `WrappedArray` column in a Spark dataset.
The `WrappedArray` contain objects, for example, I have a dataset contain following column:

```
ColA
-----
WrappedArray([id:111, type:A],[id:222,type:B])
WrappedArray([id:333, type:A],[id:444,type:C])
WrappedArray([id:555, type:B],[id:666,type:C])
```

I want to remove any element inside the `WrappedArray` with `type == A`. The desired output is like:

```
ColA
-----
WrappedArray([id:222,type:B])
WrappedArray([id:444,type:C])
WrappedArray([id:555, type:B],[id:666,type:C])
```

I was thinking about using an `UDF` and `withColumn`, and I can see that the `WrappedArray` API has the `filter` function, but can't get the syntax right.

Working on Java, but any language is okay. Any help/suggestion would be nice!

Comment: Did you check this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195507/how-to-get-data-out-of-wrapped-array-in-apache-spark-scala

Comment: just read it. That solution seems won't work if the position is not fixed if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that question is a bit different. For this I would probably be able to give you a Scala solution using an `UDF`, but not so sure on how helpful it would be. Could you add the `UDF` you have tried to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using explode,
Basic idea is to explode to the element level, and filter out where colA.type=A